# Python socket error on Windows 10045

Tags: python

```
import socket

# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))

# Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# receive all packages
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)   //Error Occurs on this line

# receive a package
print(s.recvfrom(65565))

# disabled promiscuous mode
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

When I try to run this code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/Gen/PycharmProjects/hex2float/socketerror.py", line 14, in <module>
    s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
OSError: [WinError 10045] The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced
```

This code was taken from Python document so I am confused why it does not work. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you need to delete `socket.AF_INET` from u sentence `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)`

as I use `SOCK_DGRAM` without `AF_INET` to build server successfully.